# archive app for submission

Tags: xcode4, submission

I am stuck on this

Open the Xcode project and Duplicate the “Release” configuration in the Configurations pane of the project's Info panel. Rename this new configuration “Distribution”.

I don’t see any of this in my sdk4.2

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you can find it:

1. Click on a project row in a file list

   [image]
2. If not already opened, open an Info tab (top right corner on the screenshot)

   [image]